# Why does “Witcher” returns “Witch” in results?

Tags: bug, search

This is about movies.SE but you can try this on other sites too, but it may not yield results.

[https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=“The+Witcher”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CThe+Witcher%E2%80%9D)

gives over 300 results while the tag <sup>1</sup> has only 2 questions and I have seen only one question without tag some time ago. So the relevant results are only 1%.

Can this search be fixed please ?

In response to the answer: I am using Safari on iOS 12. Keyboard is English US, but I doubt that its punctuation layout changes.

[image]

1 https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using literal unicode open/close quote characters:

```
“The+Witcher”
```

Search doesn't recognize those as quotes ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug) maybe?), so instead you have to use the standard double quote character, like so:

```
"The+Witcher"
```

Comment: It’s a bug for mobile users on iPhone. Safari specifically but keyboard is the same across apps.

Comment: @ankii Hold down the `“` key and select the straight quote. It’s annoying but it’s what you have to do

Comment: Typing on phone is already a pain @Laurel. I’d love to get it fixed. And will accept this answer then, even if staff answers.

Comment: @ankii 'tis unfortunate, but neccesary. I would love to see this added as a feature.

Comment: Filed a feature request here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340803/allow-search-to-recognize-smart-quotes-the-same-way-as-straight-quotes (cc @ankii)

Comment: @ankii This has been fixed: smart quotes should now work.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I doubt that.. [https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=“The+Witcher”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=“The+Witcher”) [https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22The+Witcher%22](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22The+Witcher%22) are wildly different

Comment: Good find. Letting you know that I filed another bug about it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344842/search-doesnt-properly-recognize-smart-quotes-and-reliably-return-the-same-resu

Answer (score 5):

You can also [change this more globally on your phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/299505/76776):

> Settings | General | Keyboard | Smart Punctuation.

iOS 11 was responsible for making smart quotes the default.

There's really no reason to keep them that way.