# Allow search to recognize smart quotes the same way as straight quotes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, special-characters

Search has a feature: enclose any specific phrase you're looking for in "quotes", and it will search for that exact phrase.

However, that operator only works with "straight quotes", and not “smart quotes”.

Ordinarily, on a desktop computer keyboard as well as on most Android devices, this isn't really an issue, since the keyboard will type straight quotes whenever the quote key is pressed. However, the iOS keyboard types smart quotes by default: to type a straight quote, one must tap and hold as if typing a special character.

This can result in [strange "bugs"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340799/why-does-witcher-returns-witch-in-results) when iOS users attempt to use exact phrase search, only to have their query somehow fail to work even if it would work right on a different device.

While some may argue that "this is a fault of iOS, not SE; this can be fixed in the settings, etc.", I think a workaround should be implemented in SE, because some non-iOS users may have special keyboards, plugins, or browser features installed that convert straight quotes into smart quotes. Also, the two types of quotes are difficult to discern on first glance, which brings up accessibility issues.

Can search please recognize “smart quotes” the same way as it does "straight quotes"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. This has been fixed. “Smart Quotes” in the search box will now be treated identically as "Regular Quotes".

Comment: Could you figure out the difference in these two links pls:  [https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=“The+Witcher”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=“The+Witcher”) [https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22The+Witcher%22](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22The+Witcher%22).. P.S. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340799/561132

Comment: @ankii they both return the same results, per design. Am I missing something?

Comment: The first one gives >300 results, the second one 21. macOS 10.14.5, Safari 12.1.1.

Comment: I am getting 356 results for each search

Comment: **1** I included address bars, search bars, and extensions in the screenshots. https://i.stack.imgur.com/raqPt.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYk6x.png **2** did you check on Safari ?

Comment: I just tested on Chromium-based Edge, and I can reproduce: the first link (smart quotes) returns 358 results, while the second returns only 21. Can you please recheck?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I can reproduce. Can you please make a new post on this one. Hard to track bugs in comments.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Filed the bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344842/search-doesnt-properly-recognize-smart-quotes-and-reliably-return-the-same-resu

Comment: @ankii They are returning the same results now.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog thanks for updating! it's fine now!