# Search doesn't properly recognize smart quotes and reliably return the same results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, special-characters

This is not a duplicate of my prior post [Allow search to recognize smart quotes the same way as straight quotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340803/allow-search-to-recognize-smart-quotes-the-same-way-as-straight-quotes), which was a feature request asking for smart quote support, as it was previously unsupported. However, the original implementation never really worked, and the developer responsible for its implementation [asked me to post a new bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340803/allow-search-to-recognize-smart-quotes-the-same-way-as-straight-quotes#comment1155487_342200).

Basically, the request asks for search to support “smart quotes” (special characters for beginning and ending quotes) the same way as "straight quotes", which are the normal identical characters typed when pressing the quote key on the keyboard. Some browsers and operating systems (e.g. Apple operating systems) automatically replace straight quotes with smart quotes, resulting in [strange "bugs"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340799/why-does-witcher-returns-witch-in-results) where phrase search somehow fails to work even if it clearly should.

The request was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), with a developer responding:

> Thanks for the suggestion. This has been fixed. “Smart Quotes” in the search box will now be treated identically as "Regular Quotes".

However, this doesn't appear to work right. [This straight quote search](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22The+Witcher%22) returns only 21 results, as would be expected, but [this smart quote search](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CThe+Witcher%E2%80%9D) returns 358 results (at the time of writing). Both searches should have returned only 21 results if this were implemented correctly.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: I have confirmed that the smart quotes you used are completely parsed out of the search on SO and here as well.  They are effectively removed while regular quotes are still honored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Smart quotes should now be converted to regular quotes in searches, and should return identical results (for real this time).